# Published program can't find CSV files

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am writing a program that populates listBoxes with data from .csv files.

It runs flawlessly in debugging/release, however when I try to publish the program it can't find the .csv / DEPLOY files.

In the solution explorer the .csv files have the "Build Action" property set to "Content", the "Copy to Output Directory" set to "Copy always", and they are set to "Include (Auto)" in the "Application Files" folder on the "Publish Tab".

When I double-click the "Setup" application that is downloaded, it successfully installs the program and then says: 'Could not find the file', and the dropdown details are:

```
************** Exception Text **************

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\aplattel\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\G6C5PO3Q.NM9\EEX9H3AC.7ZE\jump..tion_9801a5e0f1d741c2_0001.0000_5fc10f3e2273aaad\ProductA.csv'.
File name: 'C:\Users\aplattel\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\G6C5PO3Q.NM9\EEX9H3AC.7ZE\jump..tion_9801a5e0f1d741c2_0001.0000_5fc10f3e2273aaad\ProductA.csv'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path)
   at Jumper_Assemblies.JumperAssembly.JumperAssembly_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnShown(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.CallShownEvent()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.2053.0 built by: NET47REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Jumper_Assemblies
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/aplattel/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/G6C5PO3Q.NM9/EEX9H3AC.7ZE/jump..tion_9801a5e0f1d741c2_0001.0000_5fc10f3e2273aaad/Jumper_Assemblies.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.2053.0 built by: NET47REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.2053.0 built by: NET47REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.2053.0 built by: NET47REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.2053.0 built by: NET47REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.2053.0 built by: NET47REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.2053.0 built by: NET47REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
```

Any idea on what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an after build action to copy the files to a location you know about OR use relative references to the file (.\ProductA.csv).

The precise location will depend upon your file structure.

Comment: The problem was that I had the .csv files stored in the debug/release bins rather than the main program folder.                                                                                  
Solved link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b5e244c1-a409-4742-8180-46182ddb8324/attach-csv-files-to-deployed-program?forum=winformssetup
Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the problem presented:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b5e244c1-a409-4742-8180-46182ddb8324/attach-csv-files-to-deployed-program?forum=winformssetup